# Azure Container App: Only allow access over Api Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-container-apps

I want to restrict access to my [Azure Container App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-apps/) with an [Api Management](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/api-management/#overview) in Azure.

I successfully linked the Api Management with the Container App and I have activated a Subscription with an Api Key that will prevent public access over the Api Management Service Url. The problem, however, is that the Container App can still be accessed over the public Url of the Container App.

There is still the option to set the `Ingress Traffic` in the Container App to `Limited to Container Apps Environment` but then the Api Management will not have access to the Container App as well.

What is the correct way to properly secure the Container App behind an Api Management Service?

Comment: Enabling authentication on the Azure Container App while allowing the managed identity of the API Management could help.

Answer (score 6):

First, I think that it is good to explain networking architecture in Azure Container Apps.

Azure Container Apps run in the context of an environment, which is supported by a virtual network (VNET). When you create an environment, you can provide a custom VNET, otherwise a VNET is automatically generated for you.

There are two ways to deploy Container Apps environments:

1. **External** - Container Apps environments deployed as external resources are available for public requests. External environments are deployed with a virtual IP on an external, public facing IP address.
2. **Internal** - When set to internal, the environment has no public endpoint. Internal environments are deployed with a virtual IP (VIP) mapped to an internal IP address. The internal endpoint is an Azure internal load balancer (ILB) and IP addresses are issued from the custom VNET's list of private IP addresses.

I attach the image from Azure portal to show above two options:

[image]

Now going further, if you want your container app to restrict all outside access, **create an internal Container Apps environment**.

Now when it comes to deployment of the Container Apps to the Container Apps Environment, accessibility level you selected for the environment will impact the available ingress options for your container app deployments.

If you are deploying to **an external environment**, you have two options for configuring ingress traffic to your container app:

1. **Limited to Container Apps Environment** - to allow only traffic from other container apps deployed within the shared Container Apps environment.
2. **Accepting traffic from anywhere** - to allow the application to be accessible from the public internet.

[image]

If you are deploying to **an internal environment**, you also have two options for configuring ingress traffic to your container app:

1. **Limited to Container Apps Environment** - to allow only traffic from other container apps deployed within the shared Container Apps environment.
2. **Limited to vNET (Virtual Network)** - to allow traffic from the VNET to make container app to be accessible from other Azure resources or applications within the virtual network or connected to the virtual network through Peering or some type of VPN connectivity

[image]

Now in you case, what you are looking for is the architecture where you enable access to Azure Container Apps only through the Azure API Management. In this case you have to deploy Azure Container Apps Environment with **Internal** mode and set ingress traffic to **Limited to VNet** (Virtual Network).

I assume that Azure API Management can be accessible from the Internet. In this case you have to deploy Azure API Management inside an Azure Virtual Network. There are two possible modes: internal, and external. In you scenario, you can use **external** mode. More details can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet?tabs=stv2). When API Management instance in the external mode, the developer portal, API gateway, and other API Management endpoints are accessible from the public internet, and backend services are located in the Azure Virtual Network.

[image]

Here I also attach the solution architecture to show how all these components are connected together. I also have Azure Front Door here but API Management is deployed with external mode. Please remember that you will also need private DNS Zone for your Azure Container Apps Environment domain, to make it possible to refer to specific APIs from the Azure API Management using URLs, example:

https://ca-tmf-mip-vc-api--v-01.blacklacier-cf61414b.westeurope.azurecontainerapps.io

[image]

Helpful links:

[Repo with Bicep files to deploy Azure Container App with internal mode](https://github.com/zlatko-ms/az-capps-private)

[Azure Container Apps Virtual Network Integration](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/azure-container-apps-virtual-network-integration/ba-p/3096932)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your API management service has a static IP (not a consumption plan), you would need to use you own VNET:

- [Networking architecture in Azure Container Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/networking#custom-vnet-configuration)

Then using NSG, you could add an inbound rule to only allow traffic from the APIM service IP on HTTPS (TCP 443).

Answer (score 0):

Azure container apps do now seem to have the ability to restrict inbound ip addresses

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/updates/public-preview-inbound-ip-restrictions-support-in-azure-container-apps/

We have are looking at a similar architecture with a similar dilemma. Everything we have is secured with Azure b2c but if I want to make an internal container/microservice accessible to Azure Api Management I think I'd have to drop b2c (api management has no UI to log into b2c) and make it publicly accessible via the Ingress. If the inbound ip addresses are restricted to api management maybe that is ok. It does worry me that ip addresses can be spoofed although you'd hope Microsoft have thought of that.

Another alternative which I've not investigated but which does work for Azure functions is managed identities. This might not work at all with container apps though

https://www.svenmalvik.com/azure-apim-function-msi/

Comment: Also found this example which uses api managements self-hosted gateway to provide a way of exposing internal container apps

https://github.com/tomkerkhove/azure-apim-on-container-apps

The trouble with this is the costs of the self-hosted gateway which I think are eye watering

Comment: Both self-hosted gateways and virtual network support are part of the premium tier of apim. This is £2322.64 per month !!!!